# Pygame math module was not found

Tags: python, pygame

I have problem with pygame, when I try to use pygame.math it says "no math module in **init**.py", I have installed newest version from pygame website http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

math was introduced in pygame 1.10 (in link you provided there is pygame 1.9) so in order to use it you have to either compile from source repo https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame or get it from other source, but it must be version 1.10+